# Monitor network activity of specific program

Tags: proxy, get, http-headers, reverse-engineering, wireshark

I have a program that I'm trying to reverse engineer.

It gets a specific key by using HTTP GET on some URLs.
 I need to figure out the details on how this works.

The good news is that there's the option to preform these requests over an HTTP proxy.

Would anybody know of a program to monitor a specific application's network traffic?

> I've tried Wireshark, but its no giving me enough information (Headers, URL path). 
>   After Wireshark, I tried FreeProxy. The problem with FreeProxy is that it only gives headers for around 1/3 of the requests and it doesn't give the full path either.

Could anyone suggest a better alternative for monitoring the internet activity of my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recommemded another program called "mitmproxy" which worked perfectly for what I needed. Fiddler also worked, but SSL was giving me problems.

Answer (score 1):

I thought Wireshark was able to capture the full packet with all its content? If so, how can it not give you enough information? Maybe you need to revise your traffic capture config?

It's been a while since I used Wireshark, but if you have trouble capturing full packets, what you can do is use `tcpdump` to capture and write to file, then view the capture file using Wireshark. `tcpdump`'s `-s` option will allow you to set the packet size so as to capture full packets.

Comment: You're probably right, I'm a complete noob when it comes to Wireshark. Its not the data I need, though. I need something like "https://abc.site.com/x/y/z" not just an ip or host. Is this possible with Wireshark? I also need all the headers like "user-agent." How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you've captured the full packets (which Wireshark captures by default), you should have *all* that information.  You might have to open up the packet in the "detail" pane (second pane), but it should all be there.

Comment: Yep, @GuyHarris is right. You may need to look into the "application data" (or whatever it's called in Wireshark... the highest-level packet content) portion, and start wading through it. If I'm interpreting this correctly, it's just ASCII you need to fish out from there, so you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) for all my HTTP traffic monitoring.  It is very powerful and displays data in the HTTP layer only.  Wireshark will get all of your data, but it displays the details at a much lower layer.  It even has capability to decrypt SSL traffic.

Fiddler installs itself as a proxy, and configures IE and FF automatically to use it when it is on.  If you are having too much traffic mix in, then you can install Fiddler on a remote box, and point your proxy to that IP address.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I'm connecting to 127.0.0.1:8888, but it says that it can't connect to anything.

Comment: It works straight away from install.  Have you tried it with a browser?  Check firewalls?

Comment: I was able to connect by using a different computer. I do have one question though. I turned on the "Decrypt SSL traffic" option and exported the certificate to my desktop. I then transferred and installed the certificate on the machine containing the program I want to reverse-engineer. The program gives me some error about the CA Certificate. Is there anyway to bypass this, or will I have to disassemble it, etc. in  order to disable the SSL verification on the program?

Comment: The SSL cert that Fiddler generates is an obvious fake.  It is not in any chain of trust anywhere.  If you get the remote system to trust the cert, then maybe the program will assume trust based on system's trust.

Comment: I thought double clicking on the .cer file from fiddler registered it as trusted.

Comment: Try the native browser and see if it is trusted.

Comment: Yeah, browsers work. Its the program thats the issue. It says "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates." Would there be any way around this? I need to decrypt SSL traffic.